# How to unmerge rows and not column

Tags: excel, vba, merge

I have a table which contains merged cells both column and rows as shown in attached picture. I want to unmerge "Only" rows while leaving columns merged. Consider the following snippet of table. In the image attached "Contract

[image]

```
For y = 1 To lRow
        p = 1
        c = y
        d = 1
        z = lRow + y
        t = Cells(y, 1).Value
        For x = 1 To t
        Cells(z, p).Value = Cells(c, d).Value
        Cells(c, d).Select
    '      Debug.Print
        Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
        c = ActiveCell.Row
        d = ActiveCell.Column
              p = p + 1
        Next

        Next

Sub ColorMergedCells()
Dim c As Range
Dim startcolumn, endcolumn, startrow, endrow As Long
For Each c In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
If c.MergeCells And c.MergeArea.Rows.Count >= 2 Then
c.Interior.ColorIndex = 28
With c.MergeArea.Rows
                .UnMerge
'                .Formula = c.Formula
End With
'
'startcolumn = ActiveCell.Column
'endcolumn = Selection.Columns.Count + startcolumn - 1
'startrow = ActiveCell.Row
'endrow = Selection.Rows.Count + startrow - 1 

End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You cannot do this in one step, neither in Excel nor in VBA..

Comment: @FunThomas can we use a loop to solve this problem

Comment: Sure, first unmerge all and then use a loop to remerge the cells per column

Comment: @FunThomas But then how do we retain the earlier merged columns. To elucidate here, i added another picture of what we want as end results. I am using  following code to move thorugh the cells          For y = 1 To lRow
        p = 1
        c = y
        d = 1
        z = lRow + y
        t = Cells(y, 1).Value
        For x = 1 To t
        Cells(z, p).Value = Cells(c, d).Value
        Cells(c, d).Select
    '      Debug.Print
        Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
        c = ActiveCell.Row
        d = ActiveCell.Column
              p = p + 1
        Next
   
        Next

Comment: Can you please edit your question and move your code in there (and format it as code)? It's unreadable in a comment.

Comment: see that the header "no." is misaligned to its value, however the header and the values always come at second scroll from the first column. Hence I am using Selection.End(xlToRight) to move through cells. the problem however, at row 4 because the cells are merged it takes "5" as the second value, which if we repeat the merged row "Value3" will not happen. or if we have any other way to circumvent this problem. Thanks a lot

Comment: thanks @FunThomas & skkakkar  but that doesn't solve my problem. However, I could progress a bit on my cause. Appending in code a new logic (Colormergedcells sub routine) that I am trying. If you could help me a bit to progress further. what I am trying to do 1) Identify the cells of interest with rows merged 2) unmerge and duplicate the values 3) merge it back again column wise... I have been able to solve till step 2. will appreciate help on 3.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your snapshot of requirements , I have wrote a very simple code which shall appear to be crude but I have kept it this way so that you can adjust its various elements as per your actual data. Sample data taken by me and results obtained are shown in the snapshot pasted below, which is followed by code.
[image: merge_unmerge]

```
Sub Merge_unmerge()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastCol As Long
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)

    With ws
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End With
    Set rng = ws.Range("A1:D" & LastRow)
    For Each cell In rng
        cell.UnMerge
    Next cell
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If Range("A" & i) = "" Then
            Range("A" & i).Value = Range("A" & i - 1).Value
        End If
    Next i
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If Range("D" & i) = "" Then
           Range("D" & i).Value = Range("D" & i - 1).Value
        End If
    Next i
    For i = 1 To LastRow Step 2
        Range("B" & i & ":C" & i).Merge
        Range("B" & i & ":C" & i).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. I solved for the issue at hand. Posting if it helps others.

```
Sub ColorMergedCells()
Dim c As Range
Dim startcolumn, endcolumn, startrow, endrow As Long
For Each c In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
If c.MergeCells And c.MergeArea.Rows.Count >= 2 Then
c.Interior.ColorIndex = 28
startcolumn = c.Column
endcolumn = c.MergeArea.Columns.Count + startcolumn - 1
startrow = c.Row
endrow = c.MergeArea.Rows.Count + startrow - 1
With c.MergeArea.Rows
                .UnMerge
                .Formula = c.Formula
End With

For J = startrow To endrow
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Range(Cells(J, startcolumn), Cells(J, endcolumn)).Merge
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Next
```

End If
Next
End Sub